# Do additional date range filters increase the performance?

Tags: performance, date, elasticsearch, filter

To an existing, large ElasticSearch 5 index, I want to add a `date` field, containing the date of the indexation of each document. Afterwards I want to query this index, to return all documents, created in the last minute.

In the [ElasticSearch Ultimative Guide for version 1](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/1.x/_filter_order.html) it is mentioned, that adding additional filters for day, month and/or year can improve the performance drastically. Newer versions of the guide do not say so anymore.

Can I gain performance in ElasticSearch 5 with adding additional date filters?

Answer (score 4):

Depending on the size of your index, it certainly would help restrain the amount of data that gets considered for your query.

If your index contains years of data, adding a filter to only consider the documents indexed during the last minute will considerably decrease the amount of data that will be focused on for your query.

It was the case with ES 1.x and it is still the case with ES 5.x, the only difference is that in 1.x you had to take care of properly ordering your filters to use the most aggressive filters first, which is not the case anymore in 5.x as ES is now smart enough to run the most aggressive filters first to make sure to weed out unnecessary data very early during the search process.

Comment: If I filter by `date > 2017-07-18 23:58:13`, will then adding filters like `date > 2017` boost performance (due to better caching?)

Comment: Not sure how both dates relate together?

Comment: The one date would be the exact second, that I want to filter on (unlikely to be cached), the other one would be only the year part of what I'm searching for (not exact, but very likely to be cached).

Comment: ES used to index numbers (and dates) the same way as text, but in recent versions they started doing it differently using BKD tree data structures, which provides a much better performance. You can read about it [here](https://www.elastic.co/blog/apache-lucene-numeric-filters), [here](https://www.elastic.co/blog/numeric-and-date-ranges-in-elasticsearch-just-another-brick-in-the-wall) and [here](https://www.elastic.co/blog/searching-numb3rs-in-5.0). All this to say that you can trust ES that if an optimization can be made from your queries, it will make it.